# tensorflow scan on a matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, scanning

How to get the following example of scan to work?  I plan to use this example to test out some code in the function f.

```
def f(prev_y, curr_y):
  fval = tf.nn.softmax(curr_y)
  return fval

a = tf.constant([[.1, .25, .3, .2, .15],
                 [.07, .35, .27, .17, .14]])
c = tf.scan(f, a, initializer=0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(c))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `initializer=0` is not valid. As [documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan):

> If an `initializer` is provided, then the output of fn must have the same structure as `initializer`; and the first argument of `fn` must match this structure.

The output of your `f` has the same type and shape as `curr_y`, the second argument, which won't match `0`. In this case, you would need:

```
init = tf.constant([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
c = tf.scan(f, a, initializer=init)
```

For this specific case (your `f` specifically), you don't (and maybe shouldn't) need to use `tf.scan` because your `f` uses only one argument. `tf.map_fn` would do the job:

```
c = tf.map_fn(tf.nn.softmax, a)
```